# QueueMetrics, qLoader, and Asterisk not talking correctly

Tags: asterisk

I have 2 servers, one with QueueMetrics installed and the other with Asterisk and qLoader.  Both of these servers are able to communicate with each other and pass data back and forth.  The problem that I am running into is that when adding an agent to a queue, neither Queuemetrics or the Asterisk server is recognizing that the agent is being added.  I can make a call into the queue and see it being offered to the queue in real-time in QM.  When I try to add an agent to the queue, QM says that the agent is being added.  When watching the real-time monitor after the agent is added, the agent just never shows up as logged in.  I have checked the MySQL database as well and it never shows the agent as being logged in either.  I am unsure at this point what is causing the issue, and whether it is that the agent isn't being add to MySQL because of QM or because the agent available isn't being sent to the Asterisk server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need read something about queues setup and check your setup. For example this book: http://cdn.oreilly.com/books/9780596510480.pdf

Unfortanly no way troubleshoot your install without see config&debug.

Answer (score 0):

QueueMetrics uses two different channels to work with the server: it reads data from the queue_log through qloader (and that is working for you) and uses AMI plus a custom Asterisk dialplan to perform actions like logging-on agents.

You can test the AMI and whether the dialplan is included through the DbTester tool - see http://queuemetrics.com/manuals/QM_UserManual-chunked/ar01s20.html#DBTEST - note that you may need to edit the supplied dialplan to match the format of your channel names. Qm is very flexible, but you need to tell it how your environment is set-up.

Or just keep an Asterisk CLI open when trying to log in agents and see what happens.